# Content-Type application/soap+msbin1 in SOAP UI / SOAP UI PRO

Tags: web-services, api, wcf, soapui, web-api-testing

I have a WCF service and I am attempting to use it with SOAP UI PRO. On the first execution I got the following response:

> HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;' was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'.

I found out that I should have added the **Content-Type** header and I did so (i.e. **Content-Type application/soap+msbin1**).  However, the error now evolved to:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

I learned that **Binary-Encoding** is not supported in SOAP UI / SOAP UI PRO / READY API, and I'm kinda of stuck after this discovery.

I was wondering whether there is a workaround to this issue.  Hence, whether someone managed to use groovy script, plugins, libraries or something different to integrate binary-encoding in SOAP UI PRO.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you try the same using Chorme's extension `POSTMAN`, what is the result?

Comment: @Rao - The same thing exactly...

Comment: Hope you sending the right request.

Comment: Yes, the request is correct, the content-type is the issue here.

Comment: Have you checked the application logs when 400 error thrown? Also you may check for the right value for the same.

Comment: The log is clear just outputs WS related info but no errors whatsoever...

Answer (score 3):

The application/soap+msbin1 is a binary encoding of WCF. You are sending requests with text encoding. That is why the server side gives: *Bad request*.

As far as I know, SoapUI does not support the application/soap+msbin1 encoding and there is no plugin available.

If you need to test the service with SoapUI you have 2 options:

1. **Change the service (server-side) binding** to text encoding (by configuration in *web.config*). Please note that a service can have multiple bindings, co you can test a binding with text encoding, whereas WCF clients can use binary (application/soap+msbin1) encoding. Text encoding is anyway needed to achieve interoperability with non-WCF clients (such as SoapUI). You can check [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889(v=vs.110).aspx) for more.
2. **Encode your soap request into binary data** and send it as a HTTP PUT request. Of course you would also need to decode the service response to understand it. This might be a way for a one-time test, otherwise it's too cumbersome. You could do the binary encoding/decoding on-the-fly with Groovy scripting, in case you need to do many tests, but there's some programming needed.

I definitely recommend the first option.

Karel

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me

Create a Custom Binding and make sure you use

```
**<binaryMessageEncoding />**

<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="MyCustomBinding">
       <binaryMessageEncoding />
    </binding>
```

and refer to it in your endpoint.

```
 <endpoint address="https://..." binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyCustomBinding" contract="..." name="..." />
```